# how to evaluate changes in categories over time?

Tags: time-series, prediction

Last year, I administered a motor developmental test on children. This tools, categorize samples into 3 group. Now, I am going to choose 10 children from each group, repeating test to recognize whether they still belongs to the their  previous category. The question is that which statistical analysis does this process (e.g. discriminant analysis, logistic regression or…)?